# adding php stops my javascript init() working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file written in html and javascript. I have an init function that I used to initialise some variables in javascript. To make this happen I have the following tag in the body statement:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

and then later I have the function itself. All seems to work well.

```
function init() {
  // initialisation stuff here
  var arr = ["happy", "winter", "hot", "cold", "male", "female", "summer", "spring", "autumn"]; 
  document.getElementById('word').innerHTML =  arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; 
  flag = 0;
}
```

However, I now want to load some data from a file so that I can replace the arr variable in my init() function with a much longer list of words. So just below the body statement I put the following:

```
<?php
   $words = file('data.txt');
?>
```

I changed the file extension from html to php so that the php script would run before the page loads. When I change the extension to php it works fine. But as soon as I add those php lines I get an error. When I look using Develops Tools it says - Uncaught Reference Error: Init not defined.

But my init function is still there. Why would adding those php lines affect the javascript init function?

EDIT

I had the following two lines in my init function

```
// var words = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $words) . '"]' ?>;
// alert(words);
```

I thought they were commented out. But obviously not. If I remove them the code works fine.

However, although it is evident from the run-time inspection that

```
var words = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $words) . '"]' ?>;
alert(words);
```

is bringing the data into the init function, somehow it is still producing an error.

Comment: Is that all you've added? Without using the `$words` variable yet?

Comment: The javascript does not have access to the PHP words variable. You will have to output something from the words variables (as javascript)

Comment: I had these two lines in the init.   // var words = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $words) . '"]' ?>;
  // alert(words); I had assumed they were commented out. But I can see from the runtime feedback that they might not be. I have edited my question above based on this.

Comment: Use `var words = <?php echo json_encode($words); ?>` and avoid JavaScript injections.

Comment: Also, look into your page source to see what is really pasted there. I'd assume that there is a syntax error now, which makes the whole block invalid, including the init function that is there.

Comment: Interestingly, using the implode function it does seem that the data are being transferred into javascript init function. But with an error. In the source I see var words = ["female #1C6638
", "happy #37662F
", "cold #296661
", "cold #429BD4
", "summer #4FB0D1
", "summer #392766
", "male #212666
", "spring #2D5F66
", "hot #FC0518
", "female #E3B1D6
", "autumn #216637
", "male #316637
", "happy #66255A
", "female #2F6653
", "happy #FFFE00
", "hot #FF2929
", "cold #132266
"];
 There are carriage returns after each line. I wonder if this is a mac problem (I am using a mac).

Comment: Anyway this is working perfectly without the line breaks var words = <?php echo json_encode($words); ?>; Thanks so much everyone.